# ExpandableListView child height is zero or not enough

Tags: android, layout, height, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Edit:Do not put ListView in an ExpandableView. It was the first problem.Second one was my graph's height was always zero.(Look in details http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html )
These were the problems.For ListView I used just TextViews and put values in them with for loop.
For the graph problem I check the device's pixel values and setLayoutParameters with that depending on whether it is PORTRAIT or LANDSCAPE.Here is the code I used for it.It gives good values on devices that I will use but there may be a better solution.

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height=metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
if (orientation == 1) {
    SGV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height/4));
} else {
    SGV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height/2));
}
```

I'm implementing a ExpandableListView that has two different type of children which are a view and a listview.I use two different layout files for both so I have 2 child layout which are child_list.xml and child_img.xml

The problem is that if I don't set the layout width and height it gives normal width but 0 height to view and normal width and not enough height for listview so I can only see one element of listview.However if I set LayoutParameters as (1200,400) it show all listview elements.

Without setting height or width how can I show all my list elements?

Main Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/distance_fragment_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@null" >
</ExpandableListView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Group.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/groupName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

children_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/child_listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

children_list_txt

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance_list_home"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance_list_away"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyExpandableListViewAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListItems extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> mParent;

    public ExpandableListItems(Context context, ArrayList<String> parent) {
        mParent = parent;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mParent.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int i) {
        return mParent.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return mParent.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(groupPosition == 1){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.distance_child_img, null);
        ViewGroup graphArea = (ViewGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testw);
        SpeedGraphView SGV = new                                                    SpeedGraphView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            SGV.setArrays(homefirstHalfSpeedArray,homesecondHalfSpeedArray,Global.app.match.homeTeam.getTeamName());
            SGV.setPlayerArrays(awayfirstHalfSpeedArray,awaysecondHalfSpeedArray,Global.app.match.awayTeam.getTeamName());
            SGV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1200, 400));
            graphArea.addView(SGV);

        }else{
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.distance_child_list, null);

             ListView listV = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_listView);
             ListAdapter adp = new ListAdapter(getActivity());
             adp.add(new ListItem("Deneme", "Away", 200, 100));
             adp.add(new ListItem("asdas", "Away", 200, 100));
             listV.setAdapter(adp);
            // listV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1200,500));
        }
        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.distance_group, null);
        TextView tx = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
        tx.setText(ExpListItems.get(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```